# C++11: Is using std::move only safe on temporary objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, lvalue

In my code, I have something like this:

```
unordered_multimap<string, unordered_map<string, string> > mEntities;
...
vector<unordered_map<string, string> > rawEntities;
if (qi::phrase_parse(&buf[0], (&buf[0]) + buf.size(), EntityParser<char*>(), qi::space, rawEntities)) {
    for (auto &propGroup : rawEntities) {
        auto search = propGroup.find("classname");
        if (search != propGroup.end()) {
            // is stealing propGroup safe???
            mEntities.emplace(search->second, std::move(propGroup)); 
        }
    }
}
// rawEntities goes out of scope here
```

As you can see, I'm using `std::move` on an object of type deduced to `unordered_map<string, string>&`, which is obviously not `unordered_map<string, string>&&`. Still, I know for sure that because `rawEntities` goes out of scope after the `for` loop, its elements (the string->string maps) will never be used again. So I'm figuring that it's safe to steal (move) its elements data because they won't be used again.

When I run the program, it seems to work. But is this bad practice / an anti-pattern, and particularly, does the standard guarantee it is safe?

Comment: Just looking at your question title, the answer is that temporary objects are (by definition) prvalues, and `std::move` is just a cast, which is unnecessary in that case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On the contrary. Using `std::move` on temporary objects is pointless. They're already R-values, and will be deduced as R-value references when passed to functions. The whole point of `std::move` is to turn L-values into R-value references so they can be moved from.

> So I'm figuring that it's safe to steal (move) its elements data
>   because they won't be used again.

Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 4):

In general, **temporary objects are unnamed and are already rvalues**. `std::move` isn't really applicable, since it is unnamed.

When is `std::move` applicable? Whenever the object is going to expire and would no longer be required. This is what `std::move` does, it casts the value category such that it can be moved from.

It is something of an interesting use case - stealing the (filtered) contents of a container and not just the entire container.

Given the contents of the `vector` are not going to be required after the `for` loop completes, **then yes, it would work as expected**.